# Paste sheet copied from an open workbook into an existing non open workbook

Tags: vba, excel, copy

I am trying to copy "Sheet1" from the workbook I have open, labelled "source.xlsm", and paste after the last sheet of my existing workbook which is not open at the time of running, labelled "target.xlsx".

I have the below code and it seems the whole "C:\" directory does nothing. Is it even possible to put a directory in? I cannot find a way to do this without having the Target.xlsx open.

```
ActiveSheet.Select
ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Workbooks("C:\Target.xlsx").Sheets("FirstSheet")
```

Comment: Currently I have subscript out of range from the "C:\Target.xlsx" and I cannot figure out a way to target that file.

Comment: You will need to open the destination workbook first before copying the sheet.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without opening the destination workbook?

Comment: No, there isn't.  You can open it in your code and then close it after the copy though.

Comment: Thank you Tim, that was the information I needed to complete my macro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already figured it out, but a suggested edit:

```
Dim wb As WorkBook
''Open 2nd Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Archive.xlsx")

''Copy To Different Workbook
Workbooks("Source.xlsx").Sheets("Source").Copy _
         After:=wb.Sheets("Archive")

''Close 2nd Workbook
wb.Save
wb.Close
```

Comment: Thank you, this gives me an insight on how to shorten and tidy my macros as I am still learning.
Without your earlier comment, id still be messing around with this so im going to give the answer to you.

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question with the helpful information provided by Tim.

```
''Open 2nd Workbook
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Archive.xlsx"

''Copy To Different Workbook
Workbooks("Source.xlsx").Sheets("Source").Activate
ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Workbooks("Archive.xlsx").Sheets("Archive")

''Close 2nd Workbook
Workbooks("Archive.xlsx").Sheets("Archive").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

Comment: You should be able to avoid one `Activate` by combining `Workbooks("Source.xlsx").Sheets("Source").Activate` `ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Workbooks("Archive.xlsx").Sheets("Archive")` as `Workbooks("Source.xlsx").Sheets("Source").Copy After:=Workbooks("Archive.xlsx").Sheets("Archive")`.  (I assume the second `Activate` is to ensure that the archive is saved with the "Archive" sheet, rather than the "Source" sheet, being the active sheet but, if not, you can get rid of it too.)

Comment: Ignore my comment - Tim's answer incorporates it (and better)